# Why django signals are not called when I create a new entry in the table?

Tags: python, django, database, email, django-signals

Created a signal that checks the Robot table for new entries. Then compares the model and version data with the Order table, then sends an email. But nothing works. What could be the problem?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Robot)
def robot_created(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    orders = Order.objects.all()

    for order in orders:
        robot_exists = Robot.objects.filter(model=order.robot_model, version=order.robot_version).exists()

        if robot_exists:
            subject = 'text'
            message = 'text'
            from_email = 'text@gmail.com'
            recipient_list = ['text22@gmail.com']

            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
```

order.models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    robot_model = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True,null=True)
    robot_version = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True,null=True)
```

robots.models.py

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, null=False)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I tried to throw it into different folders, put the print inside the function (nothing came out)

Comment: How do you create the `Robot`, where do you load the `signals` module?

Comment: When i add  signals.post_save.connect(receiver=robot_created, sender=Robot) an error occurs cannot import name 'Robot' from partially initialized module 'robots.models'

Comment: I solved it, thanks for the hint